# Obtain encrypted credentials from server or client?

Tags: android, api, rest, encryption

I'm building an app that requires obtaining Login information from REST API service using POST method with plain text as parameter.

The credentials are encrypted in the server side. As per title, I might opt to move the encryption process to the client side which is the device itself.

So, which is safer, pulling credentials from the server or encrypt it on the client side instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform action on Server Side and Client side too as well.

Perform encryption on client side for sending login credentials.

Perform encryption on server side for getting data on client side.

Use `https` instead of `http` that will too work for you as `https` encrypts whole data of its own.

Hope it sounds..